# Citing author or year only without natbib

Tags: bibtex, citing

I have to submit this article, in which I need to cite

```
Smith [2012]
```

as opposed to

```
[Smith, 2012]
```

Easy. With `natbib` I just use `\citet`. Except that I just realised the publisher doesn't want `natbib` in my LaTeX file.

Is there an alternative, other than manually writing "Smith [2012]"?

Comment: Howcome your publisher doesn't want `natbib`.

Comment: I don't know, this is what is says: "If my paper was formatted using LaTeX, I have used an unaltered copy of the 2013 version of xxxx.sty and xxxx.bst and my LaTeX source file does not use the hyperref or geometry or natbib packages." (real file names removed)

Comment: What `BibTeX` style (the `.bst` file) does your publisher use?

Comment: Does the `xxxx.sty` file you're required to use provide its own citation-related commands by any chance? If so, you could use them instead of the (well-known) citation commands provided by the `natbib` package.

Comment: It's a modified version of named.bst I believe. Actually, now that you mention, there are instructions inside the file and `\citeauthoryear` is the command I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Whether using `biblatex` is allowed in the solution or not is unclear. However, if `biblatex` is indeed allowed, I recommend using `biblatex`'s `\textcite` (as well as `\citeauthor` and `\citeyear`), with the following tweaks:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mybiblio.bib}
@Book{Batchelor:2000,
    address     = {Cambridge, UK},
    author      = {Batchelor, G.{\,}K.},
    title       = {An Introduction to Fluid Dynamics},
    publisher   = {Cambridge University Press},
    year        = {2000},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*\bibopenparen{[}
\renewcommand*\bibcloseparen{]}
\addbibresource{mybiblio}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    All of this is discussed in \textcite{Batchelor:2000}.\\
    \citeauthor{Batchelor:2000}'s book was published in \citeyear{Batchelor:2000}.
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is not the solution I ended up using, but since it's the most complete one and my requirements didn't mention anything about not using biblatex, I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: @gozzilli What did you end up doing? Some publications require use of a custom bst file that is incompatible with biblatex, so it would be nice to know what your solution was.

Comment: Nice reference!

Comment: IEEETran Style did not works with biblatex. It use .bib, but I don't know why it don't want to work together.

Answer (score 4):

Use biblatex, and the command `\citeyear`.

Comment: As it stands, your answer is very brief. Maybe you could extend it with a MWE.

Comment: Given that the OP says that the use of a certain `yyyy.bst` bibliography style file seems to be an absolute requirement, I would suspect that using `biblatex` is going to be a viable option for him/her.

Comment: @Mico -- '**not** using `biblatex`'.

Comment: @jon Where do you get the '**not** using `biblatex`' from? I see that spec nowhere on this page...

Comment: @Jubobs -- I was actually agreeing (I think) with Mico, who was saying that using `biblatex` is likely [not] an option given the requirement that the OP use an unnamed but specific `.bst`.  It is highly unlikely that the `.bst` in question is `biblatex.bst`!

Comment: @jon - thanks for catching this! Indeed, I meant to write that it was going to the be the case that  `biblatex` would *not* be a viable option.

Comment: @jon Ah, now I understand :)

Comment: Thank you, for your post. When I run your code, it did not show bibliography at the end. How you run your file using bibtex or biblatex. when I used biblatex filename, it give error biblatex not found. What I do?