# Use `\citet` without Natbib (and without Biblatex)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I must use a predefined style which does not use Natbib nor Biblatex.

Now I have some other external Latex code which has used Natbib, and contains commands like `\citep` and `\citet`. I guess I can simply remap `\citep` to the standard `\cite`, right?

However, how would I implement sth like `\citet`?

([This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109940/citing-author-or-year-only-without-natbib) is very related, however it uses Biblatex.)

Comment: Does your predefined style support textual (`\citet`-style) citations, and/or do the author guidelines say anything about that? If it is not supported by the code, and Natbib and BibLaTeX are explicitly prohibited, then most likely the use of textual citations is also not allowed for the paper/thesis/... that you are submitting. Vice versa if it is allowed then presumably there will be some explanation or a code example on how to achieve such citations. In case it is allowed but just not implemented then you could always copy the relevant code from the `natbib` source and add that to your own

Comment: document, and then use `\citet` as you normally would without explicitly including the package.

Comment: `natbib` does some fiendishly clever things to get `\citet` to work as it does. (Well, it also does that to get `\citep` to work, but the point is that this fiendishly clever work is required to support two citation commands with slightly different output.) So if you wanted to use `\citep` and `\citet` with (roughly) their normal behaviour, you'd essentially have to copy all the things `natbib` does behind the scenes. ...

Comment: .... I'm not saying this is impossible, but at least I'd like to heavily suggest that if you for some reason can't load `natbib` (I'm guessing a fixed publisher/journal template) that same reason may also make it at least highly undesirable to add large blocks of code to the preamble. Last but not least it should be noted that `\citet` support for `natbib` also depends on the `.bst`/BibTeX style you used. So if you have to use a certain `.bst` file that is not `natbib`-compatible the necessary data is probably not going to be available at all.